# How to declare and display a variable in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I would like to declare and display a variable in Oracle.

In T-SQL I would do something like this

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(10) --Declares @A
SELECT @A = '12' --Assigns @A
SELECT @A --Displays @A
```

How can I do this in Oracle.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you're talking about PL/SQL, you should put it in an anonymous block.

```
DECLARE
    v_text VARCHAR2(10); -- declare
BEGIN
    v_text := 'Hello';  --assign
    dbms_output.Put_line(v_text); --display
END;
```

Comment: Sorry to revive an old post.  The part of this that doesn't address the original question - for me at least - is that `dbms_output.put_line` effectively does a `PRINT` statement in T-SQL.  What David posted and what I was looking for was for the last `SELECT` statement to return a result set - which can be used by the client application.  Do you know how to accomplish this?  
Thanks.

Comment: The `dbms_output.Put_line(v_text);` does the equivalent of a `PRINT @v_text;` in T-SQL... if you remember to connect your Dbms output window in SQL developer to the same Oracle conenction as your query!

Comment: If you'd rather have your Dbms output statements in your Script Output panel, this is a quick and easy tutorial. http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/enabling-dbms_output-by-default-in-sql-developer/

Answer (score 10):

If using sqlplus you can define a variable thus:

```
define <varname>=<varvalue>
```

And you can display the value by:

```
define <varname>
```

And then use it in a query as, for example:

```
select *
from tab1
where col1 = '&varname';
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that, server output is on otherwise output will not be display;

sql> **set serveroutput on;**

```
declare
  n number(10):=1;
begin
  while n<=10
 loop
   dbms_output.put_line(n);
   n:=n+1;
 end loop;
end;
/
```

**Outout:**
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Answer (score 3):

If you are using pl/sql then the following code should work :

set server output on -- to retrieve and display a buffer

```
DECLARE

    v_text VARCHAR2(10); -- declare
BEGIN

    v_text := 'Hello';  --assign
    dbms_output.Put_line(v_text); --display
END; 

/
```

-- this must be use to execute pl/sql script

Answer (score -1):

Did you recently switch from MySQL and are now longing for the logical equivalents of its more simple commands in Oracle? Because that is the case for me and I had the very same question. This code will give you a quick and dirty print which I think is what you're looking for:

```
Variable n number
begin
    :n := 1;
end;
print n
```

The middle section is a PL/SQL bit that binds the variable.  The output from print n is in column form, and will not just give the value of n, I'm afraid.  When I ran it in Toad 11 it returned like this

```
        n
---------
        1
```

I hope that helps