# SQL Server equivalent in Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm new in Oracle database. What I need is equivalent query in Oracle like this example from SQL Server (reading results in Management Studio). On Oracle side, I'm using Golden6 from Benthic Software.

```
declare @n integer
set @n = 100;
select * from table where id >= @n and id <= @n + 50
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need this in an procedure or just as query?

Comment: Just as query. To read results in Golden6 grid.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564283 . (Not quite the same question, but the accepted answer should answer your question.)

Comment: @Mark Bannister: It doesn't help me :(

Comment: Or I can use Oracle SQL Developer...

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653423/how-do-i-use-variables-in-oracle-sql-developer) help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID NUMBER);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (100);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (10);

DEFINE n = 100;

SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE id BETWEEN &n AND &n + 50;
```

[image: proff]

You can try to run this script in [dbForge Studio for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/) (trial or free express version).