# Java PL/SQL 'Execute Immediate'

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql

I am programming Java application on Oracle database. The PL/SQL statement I am using is:

```
DECLARE
USER_COUNT INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO USER_COUNT FROM dba_users WHERE username=?;
  IF (USER_COUNT = 0) THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER ? IDENTIFIED BY ?';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE, CREATE ANY INDEX TO ?';
  ELSE
    raise_application_error(-20101, 'User ? already exists. Please drop it or choose another username.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

But I got a lot of 'invalid column index' errors if there are quotes around question marks. For instance:

```
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER ? IDENTIFIED BY ?';
```

is not working, but

```
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CREATE USER ? IDENTIFIED BY ?;
```

is good.

However if I choose to use second form, I got another syntax error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 6, column 23:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:

 ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
 <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
 continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
 sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
 date <a string literal with character set specification>
 <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
 <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
 <an alternat
```

Please advise what to do.

Comment: Any reason you don't just run the 3 statements from Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
DECLARE
   USER_COUNT   INTEGER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT (*)
     INTO USER_COUNT
     FROM dba_users
    WHERE username =?;
  IF USER_COUNT = 0 THEN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER  '||?|| 'IDENTIFIED BY  '||?;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE, CREATE ANY INDEX TO  '|| ?;
  ELSE
    raise_application_error(-20101, 'User ? already exists. Please drop it or choose another username.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: You forgot the `?` in the error message.

Comment: I really dont  know java ..so I assumed '?' is a bind variable passed it via JAVA frontend. Correct me if am wrong.btw in oracle we use '&; if we want to pass bind variables to anonymous blocks

Answer (score 2):

If `?` is a bind variable, you can't use those in a `create user` statement. It needs the complete literal text.

btw did you really mean `CREATE ANY INDEX`? That will let the new user index any table in the entire database. Normally plain `CREATE INDEX` should be sufficient.

It would better to define one or more roles in advance, and then just grant those to the new user, rather than hardcoding [every possible privilege](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9013.htm). Should the user be allowed to create views, procedures, types etc? If it's going to be a developer account, should it be able to debug code and define locks? And so on...

(Just out of interest, do you write Java in uppercase, or just PL/SQL?)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use bind variables when working with DDL in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

You can refer @ below link, a better explaination is available.

[Create user from string variables in a PL/SQL block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731832/create-user-from-string-variables-in-a-pl-sql-block)