# Defining variables Oracle script

Tags: sql, oracle, popup, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to use variables in a Oracle SQL script. Following the [How to declare variable and use it in the same SQL script? (Oracle SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564283/how-to-declare-variable-and-use-it-in-the-same-sql-script-oracle-sql) post I have defined my variables as follows:

```
DEFINE dummyvar INT := 1;
SELECT '&dummyvar' FROM DUAL;
```

This leads however to popup's asking for a value when executing the script (when reusing a variable it keeps generating popups asking for a value). Is it possible to prevent the generation of popups when a value for a variable is defined?  so in the example above I want to prevent the generation of a popup; when a variable is defined as:

```
DEFINE dummyvar INT;
SELECT '&dummyvar' FROM DUAL;
```

a popup may be generated to enter the popup.

This for the execution of the script in  SQL Developer.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is specifically about SQL Developer (or PL/SQL Developer, or Toad, or something else), please confirm and tag the question. It's not clear what kind of "Oracle script" this is.

Comment: Edited the question to add reference to  SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you run a stored query or script, SQL*Plus substitutes the value of variable for each substitution variable referencing variable (in the form &variable or &&variable). SQL*Plus will not prompt you for the value of variable in this session until you UNDEFINE variable.

If the value of a defined variable extends over multiple lines (using the SQL*Plus command continuation character), SQL*Plus replaces each continuation character and carriage return with a space. For example, SQL*Plus interprets

```
DEFINE TEXT = 'ONE-
TWO-
THREE'
```

as

```
DEFINE TEXT = 'ONE TWO THREE'
```

You should avoid defining variables with names that may be identical to values that you will pass to them, as unexpected results can occur. If a value supplied for a defined variable matches a variable name, then the contents of the matching variable are used instead of the supplied value.

Some variables are predefined when SQL*Plus starts. Enter DEFINE to see their definitions.

Examples

To assign the value MANAGER to the variable POS, type:

```
DEFINE POS = MANAGER
```

If you execute a command containing a reference to &POS, SQL*Plus substitutes the value MANAGER for &POS and will not prompt you for a POS value.

To assign the CHAR value 20 to the variable DEPARTMENT_ID, type:

```
DEFINE DEPARTMENT_ID = 20
```

Even though you enter the number 20, SQL*Plus assigns a CHAR value to DEPARTMENT_ID consisting of two characters, 2 and 0.

To list the definition of DEPARTMENT_ID, enter

```
DEFINE DEPARTMENT_ID
DEFINE DEPARTMENT_ID = "20" (CHAR)
```

This result shows that the value of DEPARTMENT_ID is 20.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `VAR` instead of define if you need specific datatype. `INT` is not valid in `VAR` and only valid in SQL, PL/SQL.

This works in SQL developer using RUN script (F5).

```
VAR dummyvar NUMBER;
EXEC :dummyvar := 1;
SELECT :dummyvar value FROM DUAL;
```

This works on SQL* Plus.Note the correct syntax for `DEFINE`. You were using `:=` instead of `=`. Also, enclosing it within quotes would cause it to ignore the value.

```
DEFINE dummyvar  = 1;
SELECT &dummyvar FROM DUAL;
```