# How to use a local variable in oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some MariaDB SQLs that are called by a bash script, this script set the start and end dates for the queries, but now the project will use Oracle DB.

So, I have something like this in MariaDB SQL:

```
SET @date_start := '2000-01-01';
SET @date_end := '2001-01-01';
SELECT * FROM user WHERE birth BETWEEN @date_start AND @date_end;
```

And I couldn't find anything like that in Oracle SQL, already tried `DECLARE`, `DEFINE`, `WITH`, but nothing works

Comment: You can define variables for SQL*Plus/SQLCL scripts, accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564283/how-to-declare-variable-and-use-it-in-the-same-oracle-sql-script) shows couple of options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use parameters in Oracle, you have to use PL/SQL.  However, if you just want to parameterize a single query, you can use a CTE:

```
WITH params AS (
      SELECT DATE '2000-01-01' as date_start,
             DATE '2001-01-01' as date_end
      FROM dual
     )
SELECT u.*
FROM params CROSS JOIN
     user u
WHERE u.birth BETWEEN params.date_start AND params.date_end;
```

Similar logic works in just about any database (although `dual` may not be needed and the date constants might have different formats).

Comment: Thank you! Worked! I was using the WITH clause wrong.