# Oracle SQL alternative to using DEFINE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm currently using
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0

The following doesn't work for me ...

```
-- Since PL/SQL 20.2.0.175
DEFINE usr = 'YourName';
SELECT * FROM Department WHERE CreatedBy = '&usr';
```

Can someone give me an equivalent for my version?

Thanks!

Comment: what does "not work" mean?  are you running this in sqlplus?

Comment: Running it in "Toad Data Point" .   I get  the error  "ORA-00900: Invalid SQL statement"

Comment: DEFINE is a SQL*Plus command, it won't work elsewhere (OK, it *might* work somewhere, e.g. SQL Developer, but it won't work in TOAD). Therefore, would `select * from department where created_by = :usr` be OK for you?

Comment: I don't know Toad Data Point, but I know in Toad there's the opportunity to run commands as a script. If that option is available in Toad Data Point, that's probably what you need. Also, @Littlefoot, your comment is wrong; most Oracle-related GUIs that I've come across have a way of running SQL*Plus commands.

Comment: Does [how-to-declare-variable-and-use-it-in-the-same-oracle-sql-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564283/how-to-declare-variable-and-use-it-in-the-same-oracle-sql-script) answer your question?

Comment: @Littlefoot  the first line is also giving me an error `DEFINE usr = 'YourName';`  So I'm not sure how I would define it

Comment: @DavidLukas  I did see that link.  But I can only get a solution to work with the `INTO` command which will only accept 1 return value.  I need to return rows.   

e.g 

`
DECLARE
TmpVar varchar(20);
MY_ID varchar(20) := 'abce3udsa'

BEGIN
    SELECT ColumnValue into TmpVar FROM TableName
    WHERE ID = MY_ID;
END;
`

Comment: @Boneist - thanks for the suggestion.  It seems the `DEFINE` keyword was introduced only for later versions so I don't think I'd be able to get it to work

Comment: @Littlefoot  still got the  `ORA-00900: Invalid SQL statement`  error  :-(

Comment: If you're running it in TOAD, then there's nothing I'd like to add to my previous comment: DEFINE won't work there.

Comment: @bezbiker Try: ``with mytab m as (select 'abce3udsa' as my_id from dual) n SELECT * FROM TableName inner join mytab on m.id=n.my_id;``

Comment: @bezbiker what version of Toad Data Point are you using?

Comment: @Boneist   Toad Data Point 5.4.0.360

Comment: @DavidLukas giving me a missing keyword error.   is `m.id` correct.  What is the 'id' reference?

Comment: @bezbiker Sorry. ``with mytab as (select 'abce3udsa' as my_id from dual) SELECT * FROM TableName m inner join mytab n on m.id=n.my_id;``

Comment: OH YEAH!!!  that works @DavidLukas  Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @DavidLukas one more question.   If I want two queries to use the value in my_id how do  I run it?   The following fails with error "Table or view does not exist)
`WITH mytab as (select 'abce3udsa' as my_id from dual) 
SELECT * FROM TableName1 m1 inner join mytab n on m1.id=n.my_id;
SELECT * FROM TableName2 m2 inner join mytab n on m2.id=n.my_id;`

Comment: @bezbiker The with works only within one SQL (select). I can't think of anything anymore. Maybe take a look [here](https://stackify.dev/376289-variables-in-toad-scripts), but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What about this? [You may choose to install the Procedural Option or correct the actual syntax.](https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00900-invalid-sql-statement/)

Comment: thanks @DavidLukas will have a look at them later today.