# Select where X = variable

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

Im trying to write an Oracle SQL statement where I want to update a lot of rows connected to one id.
I've managed to solve the update query, but now when I'm refactoring I would like to change so that I get a prompt where I write in this ID instead of changing it on every update statement (which is what I'm doing currently)

I found a snippet

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
  sn   varchar2(80);
begin
  sn := '&SerialNumber';
  dbms_output.put_line(sn);
end;
```

which works perfectly, however, I'm not sure how to use this variable now.
Ideally, I would like to use it like this:

```
  set serveroutput on;
declare
  sn   varchar2(80);
begin
  sn := '&SerialNumber';
  dbms_output.put_line(sn);
end;
/
SELECT * FROM stupidtable where stupidcolumn = sn;
```

but this yields

```
ORA-00904: "SN": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
```

I'm very new to Oracle and would like some help with this. Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare variable and use it in the same Oracle SQL script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564283/how-to-declare-variable-and-use-it-in-the-same-oracle-sql-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a substitution variable in a query, then you don't need to populate it in PL/SQL and can use it directly in the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column_name = '&substitutionVariable';
```

You could also use a bind variable:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  column_name = :bindVariable;
```

> I want to use the same `substitionVariable` in a lot of UPDATE statements

[Use `&&` rather than `&`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/using-substitution-variables-sqlplus.html#GUID-C6BE6E41-821F-413E-B4B1-56AAE4A46298) if you want SQL*Plus to implicitly define a variable to store the substitution variable:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column_name = '&&substitutionVariable';

SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE column_name = '&&substitutionVariable';

-- Once the variable is defined you can use either single or double ampersands.
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE column_name = '&substitutionVariable';
```

or, use `DEFINE` to explicitly define the variable:

```sql
DEFINE substitutionVariable = Something

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column_name = '&substitutionVariable';

SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE column_name = '&substitutionVariable';

-- Once the variable is defined you can use either single or double ampersands.
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE column_name = '&&substitutionVariable';
```

Or you can use bind variables and define a variable:

```sql
VARIABLE bindVariable VARCHAR2(20);

BEGIN
  :bindVariable := 'Something';
END;
/ 

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE column_name = :bindVariable;

SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE column_name = :bindVariable;

-- Once the variable is defined you can use either single or double ampersands.
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE column_name = :bindVariable;
```

Comment: Deleted my last answer because it was poorly phrased. 
I tried this and it works well, but seeing as I want to use the same substitionVariable in a lot of UPDATE statements, how do I only get the prompt once? Thank you! :)